# Solidworks: Make a copy of a sketch on a different plane

Tags: solidworks

I have Sketch 1. It's on Plane 1. There's a different Plane 2, and I want to make Pketch 2 which is simply the entities in Sketch 1 copied to Sketch 2. I don't want to copy-paste, because I want to have their constrains preserved.

Doing "Convert Entities" doesn't help, because the shapes become different, since they are projected to the plane.

Comment: What do you mean by different plane 2? Do you mean front and top ... planes ? could you add a photo?

Comment: In my case the angle between the two planes is 60.

Comment: Try mirror plane, if it's not what you want, then lemme know.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad I have no idea what "Mirror Plane" is. I googled for it and found something related to assemblies, while I'm working on a mere part. If it exists, can you tell me where it is in the interface? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "Constraints Preserved", do you just mean that it should still be fully defined, or that it should be controlled by the original sketch (in the way 'convert entities' would if it were flat?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: 
Select the entity you want to copy.

Step 2: Select the plane you want to copy the sketch to.

Step 3: Go to Insert $\rightarrow$  Derived Sketch.

Then you'll see it makes the exact copy of the entity in the second plane.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a sketch you already must have a sketch so I created one.Now I am gonna close this sketch.
    1. Now I am going to select the sketch on the feature tree at the left and I will press Right Ctrl+C, you need to hold Ctrl and then press C.
       Now I have made a plane as a reference and moved it a little bit to make it more clear, you do not need to create one, you can copy sketch to whatever plane you want.
       I am going to start a sketch on this plane, and then I will just press ight Ctrl+V, hen the sketch should appear.
       As you can see the same sketch was copied to a different plane, it is an easy way to save your time, if you want the same sketch on parallel planes you can use Convert Entities.